# What is the function constructor in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance

In the browser (chrome at least) functions are instances of `Function`

```
setTimeout instanceof Function
// true
```

However in node, they are not

```
setTimeout instanceof Function
// false
```

So what is `setTimeout`'s constructor if not `Function`?

Comment: The constructor **is** a function. Try `typeof setTimeout.constructor`

Comment: I know its *a* function, I'm asking which function

Comment: Using node version 6.5.0, 'Function.prototype.check = true;
console.log(setTimeout.check);' prints true for me

Comment: @Sergeon i'm on node 6.3.0. Strange.

Comment: these return a `Timeout` unlike the browser which returns a `number`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - the timer functions, when called, returns a `Timeout`, but the function itself should inherit from `Function`

Comment: @Sergeon Can't reproduce that on [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs) (node v6.7 linux/amd64)

Comment: Btw, does it even *have* to be `instanceof Function`?

Comment: I get the same result as @Sergeon on 5.3.0, it returns `true`

Comment: `i'm on node 6.3.0. Strange` - it is strange, since you use the 6.x branch of node, why not use 6.9.1 - the latest recommended version for most users

Comment: Also, in repl.it it doesn't work on any function attached to `net`, `console`, `crypto` and most other Node functions, but natives like `Math.max.check` returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the constructor is `Function`, but the one from another realm.

If you run this code

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(setTimeout.constructor.prototype));
```

you get an array with the typical `Function.prototype` methods like `call`, `apply` and `bind`.

So I guess it's somewhat analogous to what happens in web browsers when you borrow `setTimeout` from an iframe:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var win = iframe.contentWindow;
console.log(win.setTimeout instanceof Function);     // false
console.log(win.setTimeout instanceof win.Function); // true
```

Comment: Not sure why they do this, though.